# How to remove CSS underline?

Tags: css, wordpress, blogs

I have a blog but most text seems to get underlined automatically. I am trying to find the text-decoration: underline but I can't seem to locate it. This is my blog

www.latestforpc.com

This is the line that causes the underline but I can't find it in style.css

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any text except for links to be underlined. Are you referring to links?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers I fixed it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web browsers are designed to add default styling to page elements even without that styling being explicity mentioned in the page's stylesheet. In order to change this default behavior, you have to add this code to style.css:
`a { text-decoration: none; }`
This will overwrite the browsers default styling for your links, and in this case, remove the underline.

Answer (score 4):

If you `inspect` a link in your browser, like you did, you can find that style, and it also shows you in which CSS file the style is declared.

In this case it says `'User agent stylesheet'`. That actually means that it is a default style in your browser (the stylesheet that is built in into your *user agent*). So that's why you cannot find it.

Now, to fix it, you can add a rule to style.css that overrules this default style:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

That should be enough. The styles in your css file have higher priority than the defaults of the browser.

Comment: That's correct. The browser by default underlines all 'a' elements so you need to override the default behavior by adding

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following at the bottom of your CSS;

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and if you want your links to appear underlined when hovering over them, also add;

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Done!

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted (and thanks to the upvoter who brought the answer back to 0). StackOverflow is not a competition you know!

Comment: It's not a competition, but people are free to downvote an answer if they think it is not useful. In this case, that might be because you don't explain the reason why the problem exists, and the fact that you specify *at the bottom* (while that doesn't matter in this case) suggests that you don't fully understand the problem yourself.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but since the questioner is clearly new to CSS, I didn't want to confuse them by explaining the whole styling priority stack. I think we can both agree that putting the new style at the bottom would solve the problem if there was another rule further up, and if there was no rule then it wouldn't matter - even if it is not quite best practice.

Comment: Misunderstanding of the questioner about this stack is the core of the problem. Questioner searches for a (custom) style that doesn't exist, because it is a browser default. So it makes sense that the main purpose of an answer to this question should be to point out this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have multiple style sheets on your site, so that style could be in any of the style sheets. You  might try adding the following in your master css file to override the other style sheets:

```
a { text-decoration: none !important;}
```

Comment: `!important` is completely unnecessary. You should use it as little as possible anyway, and above that, it doesn't solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are many "browser stylesheets" in browsers like user agent stylesheet in chrome. They are pretty good but sometimes we need to get rid of them. So we use "reset.css"

Or you can only add

```
* {text-decoration:none;}
```

if you just want to get rid of the underline